# How can I select distinct number of values from a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, count, distinct

The database contains a `REGISTRATION` table and `STUDENT` table.

The columns of `REGISTRATION` table are :

```
CourseID, StudentID, CourseCode, Score, Year
```

The `CourseCode` column contains the codes of courses like `CS-101`, `MS-202` (each student ID is registered to many courses). I need to find the names and ID's of students taking more than 3 courses.

I have tried:

```
Select distinct 
    CourseRegistrations.S_ID, Students.FirstName
from 
    Students, CourseRegistrations
where 
    Students.StudentID = CourseRegistrations.StudentID 
group by
    CourseRegistrations.S_ID, Students.FirstName 
having 
    count(distinct CourseRegistrations.CourseCode) > 3
```

but this is showing all records of file.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

`Distinct` is not need if you used `GROUP BY`

```
Select CusReg.S_ID
from Students stud join CourseRegistrations CusReg
ON stud.StudentID=CusReg.StudentID 
GROUP BY CourseRegistrations.S_ID 
having count(CusReg.CourseCode)>3
```

**Dont Use OLD Style Joins**

[SOURCE](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
Select CourseRegistrations.StudentID, count(CourseRegistrations.CourseCode)
from Students, CourseRegistrations
where Students.StudentID=CourseRegistrations.StudentID 
GROUP BY CourseRegistrations.StudentID
having count(CourseRegistrations.CourseCode)>3
```